# "Can't pickle generator objects" in Apache Beam - Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm getting the following error while running the DirectRunner:
*can't pickle generator objects [while running 'Assign Side Columns']*

The error is popping up when the beam is writing the "mapped rows" to BigQuery.

Any idea where this error is coming from?

```
def assign_columns(row, mapping):
    main_account = row['filepath_platform_id']
    main_report = row['filepath_report_name']
    for _mapping in mapping:
        _side_account = _mapping['account_id']
        _side_report = _mapping['report_name']
        if main_account == _side_account and main_report == _side_report:
            _cols = json.loads(_mapping['mapping'])
            row = renames_columns(row, _cols)
    yield row


def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    options = PipelineOptions(flags=argv)
    options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session
    table_spec = 'SELECT * FROM `nextwork-staging.datalake.v_mapping_reports`'
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:

        common_options = options.view_as(CommonOptions)

        file_metadata = (
            p
            | 'Create empty PCollection' >> beam.Create(['Start'])
            | 'Load Input Location' >> beam.ParDo(CreateFilesFromGlobByDate(common_options.input, None, None, None, common_options.starting_date, common_options.ending_date, common_options.only_last_file_from_input))
        )

        rows = (
            file_metadata | 'GetIncomeAccessFn' >> beam.ParDo(GetIncomeAccessFn())
            | 'Map to regular dictionary' >> beam.Map(lambda x: dict(x))
            | 'TransformDate' >> beam.ParDo(TransformDateFromStringFn())

        )

        side_input = (
            p
            | 'ReadTable' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query=table_spec, use_standard_sql=True)
            | 'Map Columns' >> beam.Map(lambda x: dict(x))
        )

        mapped_rows = (
            rows | 'Assign Side Columns' >> beam.Map(assign_columns, mapping=beam.pvalue.AsIter(side_input))
            | 'Rename column' >> beam.Map(renames_columns, names={'site': 'campaign'})
            | 'TransformForBigQuery' >> beam.ParDo(TransformForBigQueryFn())
        )

        gcp_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)

        (
            mapped_rows
            | 'WriteToBigQueryUsingParameter' >> bigquery_file_loads.BigQueryBatchFileLoads(
                destination=_get_table_name,
                schema=_get_schema,
                create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
                write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                additional_bq_parameters=_get_additional_bq_parameters,
                custom_gcs_temp_location=gcp_options.temp_location
            )
        )
```